# IF Statement checking for field = null Before Insert Syntax Error

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I have a table with one record that has default values for many
things. It has one record with (several fields)/columns.

When a record is inserted I want to test the record for a null value
and if it is null update it with a default value in the one record table

I do not know if this makes sense since default values can be set in mysql
but I want to have a user update default values rather than a programmer.

To do this I created a trigger for before insert but there is a syntax error
on the if statement, what am I doing wrong?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Xy6B.jpg)

Comment: You should add your code to the post rather than an image of the code. Adding some example data rows so that we can get a feel for the set is also helpful.

Comment: Please post your code as text in a code block.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `than` when it should be `then`; the syntax checker is picking up on that.

```
if new.Wall_stud is NULL then
 ...
end if;
```